# print random characters without repeat in square?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, math, random

I'm generating random characters via my code below:

```
static void printRandomWhatEver(int NUMBER_OF_CHARACTER,
                                int NUMBER_OF_LINES,
                                char char1, char char2) {
    int DIFFERENCE_SQUARE = 4;
    char oldChar, newChar, random;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHARACTER; i++) {
        random = getRandomCharacter(char1, char2);
        if ((i + 1) % NUMBER_OF_LINES == 0) { // new line each new NUMBER_OF_LINE
            System.out.println(random);
        } else {
            System.out.print(random);
        }
    }

}
```

My getReandomCharacter:-

```
private static char getRandomCharacter(char ch1, char ch2) {
    return (char) (ch1 + Math.random() * (ch2 - ch1 + 1));
}
```

All working fine, what i need is the `chars` inside square 2*2 numbers to not be **equal**, here is image to explain what i need.

[image]

The digit *4* is in the same square:-

```
**
**
```

How i can prevent digits to be equal in a part of square?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "similar" do you mean "equal"? The word "similar" is usually used for a relation which is weaker than equality. If it is a weaker relation, please explain what it is.

Comment: @JohnColeman indeed yes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just store the last line of your output, and compare the digit at position `N` to the digits `last_line[N-1]`, `last_line[N]` and `last_line[N+1]`. Take care of the array boundaries for `N-1` and `N+1`.

But you should be aware that you reduce the strength of your random number generator this way. To a human it will most likely look "more random", though.

But there may be even more patterns a human may recognize as "not random", e.g. sequential digits:

```
154
298
364
```

Comment: Right, the random became not random indeed.

Comment: Yes.  Having posted my answer I thought about it some more.  You can produce one line at a time with either 2 (at the ends) or 3 (in the middle) digits cut out of the selection.  I still prefer shuffling to random picking as it eliminates repicking incorrect numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeats you are better off shuffling rather than picking randomly.  You will have to repeatedly select different groups of digits to shuffle to avoid repeats.

To start, pick four digits from [0..9] and shuffle them:

```
0 1
2 3
```

Working from left to right, the next two digits come from [0, 2, 4..9] with 1 and 3 omitted:

```
0 1 7
2 3 8
```

Repeat the process, adding two from the eight possible digits at a time.

Use a similar "pick two from seven" process to add digits in the next row.  You only have seven digits to pick from because it is dangerous to pick an '8' in the given configuration:

```
0 1 7
2 3 8
1 8
```

Would be an error, so the '8' cannot be picked:

```
0 1 7
2 3 8
1 5
```

Is safe.

Once you move away from the left hand edge, you will be picking from six, as there will be four digits in the row above that you must avoid.

ETA: Working with two rows is overly complex.  Generate one row at a time, with any existing adjacent digits cut out of the pre-shuffle selection.  That will be 3 digits in the row above, plus the previous digit in the current row, with appropriate adjustments for left and right boundaries.

Comment: I believe there is a better way..?